# Gdalinfo and QuantumGIS does not recognize Spatial Reference even though Python does

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, geocoding

I apply the following Spatial Reference to a file:

```
spatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
spatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(3411)    
outraster.SetProjection(spatialRef.ExportToWkt() )

geotransform = (-3850000.0, 25000.0 ,0.0 ,5850000.0, 0.0, -25000.0)
outraster.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
```

If I use "icechart.GetGeoTransform()" and "icechart.GetProjection()" in Python, the output looks correct.

```
>>>icechart = gdal.Open(r'C:\Users\max\Desktop\test\icechart_persistencemap.tif')
>>>icechart.GetProjection()
'PROJCS["NSIDC_Sea_Ice_Polar_Stereographic_North",GEOGCS["GCS_Unspecified datum based upon 
the Hughes 1980 ellipsoid",DATUM["D_",SPHEROID["Hughes_1980",6378273,298.279411123064]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Stereographic_North_P
ole"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",70],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],PARAMETER
["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]'

>>>icechart.GetGeoTransform()
(-3850000.0, 25000.0, 0.0, 5850000.0, 0.0, -25000.0)
```

However, gdalinfo tells me that there is no Spatial Reference defined, neither does QuantumGIS.

When I get the Projection and Geotransform from another file, rather than defining it manually, gdalinfo finds the Spatial Reference:

```
outraster.SetGeoTransform(icechart.GetGeoTransform())
outraster.SetProjection(icechart.GetProjection())
```

Also when I reproject the raster above with gdalwarp, gdalinfo and QGIS recognize the Spatial Reference:

```
os.system('gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:3411 -tr 25000 -25000 -t_srs EPSG:3575 -of GTiff ' 
+ infile + ' ' + outfile)
```

So what is wrong with the first lines of code in this post? Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found an answer, even though I do not know why.

This does NOT work:

```
spatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
spatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(3411)
outraster.SetProjection(spatialRef.ExportToWkt() )
outband.FlushCache()
```

However THIS does work:

```
spatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
spatialRef.ImportFromProj4('+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs')
outraster.SetProjection(spatialRef.ExportToWkt() )
outband.FlushCache()
```

Could it be that gdal does not like the Wkt representation of EPSG:3411 but is happy with the one created from the proj4 version? ( Proj4 and WKT are taken from [here](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3411/) or from gdal library.)